# Guardar TEXTO de un SELECT en MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysqli

Estoy guardando los datos de mi formulario en una base de MySQL con PHP, el problema es, que cuando guardo los datos, por obvia me toma el value y no el texto, **me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma en que tome el texto dado que el value lo uso para llenar el input de abajo.**
Dejo el código y un ejemplo por si no me he explicado bien. 
Gracias.

```html
<html>
<!--Con POST los valores del formulario viajan ocultos hacia el script de destino---------------------------------------------------------->
<form name="mantenimiento_mdf" id="mantenimiento_mdf" action='bases/guardar.php' method='POST'>
  <table width="100%">
    <br />
    <p class="one" align="center"><strong>MANTENIMIENTO A CUARTOS DE EQUIPO Y COMUNICACIONES: MDF</strong></p>
    <br />
    <tr>
      <td><label for="unidad"><strong>Unidad:</strong></label></td>
      <td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Función que se ejecuta cada vez que se selecciona una unidad.
        function cambioUnidad()
        {
            document.getElementById('showSitio').value=document.getElementById('unidad').value;
        }
    </script>
    <select name="unidad" id='unidad' onchange='cambioUnidad();' required>
        <option value="">Seleccione Unidad:</option>
        <option value="1454">Almacén Delegacional Puebla</option>
        <option value="40012">Area de Auditoria, Quejas y Responsabilidades</option>
        <option value="2528">Centro de Capacitación Puebla</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="sitio"><strong>Sitio:</strong></label></td>
      <td> 
    <!-- input donde se mostrara el sitio -->
    <input type='text' name="sitio" id='showSitio' readonly>
  </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendiras que hacerlo en javascript.  Ya sea cambiar el value del input o enviar lo que necesitas por ajax.

Comment: ¿Qué tan importante es que el value de tus options sean esos números? Digo, podrías simplemente cambiar el valor de los values por el valor que quieres optener

Comment: @Diego Saravia Los uso para llenar el input que se encuentra abajo, si los cambio por el texto abajo se pondría el texto también y pues no tendría sentido.

Comment: @alanfcm algún manual o ejemplo? Nunca he usado ajax :c

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Obtener el valor de un option del select con JQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59178/obtener-el-valor-de-un-option-del-select-con-jquery)

Comment: @DiegoSaravia No, en en enlace que pones, llena el input de abajo con el mismo nombre que seleccionas, eso no lo quiero hacer, EL CODIGO HACE EXACTAMENTE LO QUE QUIERO, SELECCIONAR UNA UNIDAD Y PONER EL NÚMERO DE DICHA UNIDAD ABAJO. 

Lo que quiero es que al momento de GUARDAR LOS DATOS DE FORMULARIO ME TOME EL TEXTO DEL SELECT, NO EL VALUE, para que en la BD salga algo asi:

unidad: Almacén 
sitio: 1454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias hacerlo con Ajax, pero va a ser un poco mas complicado ya que tendrias que investigar primero sobre el tema.  Te dejo un ejemplo en el que cambiarias el valor del input usando un mapa de valores.

```html
<html>
<!--Con POST los valores del formulario viajan ocultos hacia el script de destino---------------------------------------------------------->
<form name="mantenimiento_mdf" id="mantenimiento_mdf" action='bases/guardar.php' method='POST'>
  <table width="100%">
    <br />
    <p class="one" align="center"><strong>MANTENIMIENTO A CUARTOS DE EQUIPO Y COMUNICACIONES: MDF</strong></p>
    <br />
    <tr>
      <td><label for="unidad"><strong>Unidad:</strong></label></td>
      <td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Función que se ejecuta cada vez que se selecciona una unidad.
        function cambioUnidad(unidad)
        {
            var map = {
              "Almacén Delegacional Puebla": 1454,
              "Area de Auditoria, Quejas y Responsabilidades": 40012,
              "Centro de Capacitación Puebla": 2528
            };
            document.getElementById("showSitio").value = map[unidad.value];
        }
    </script>
    <select name="unidad" id='unidad' onchange='cambioUnidad(this);' required>
        <option value="">Seleccione Unidad:</option>
        <option value="Almacén Delegacional Puebla">Almacén Delegacional Puebla</option>
        <option value="Area de Auditoria, Quejas y Responsabilidades">Area de Auditoria, Quejas y Responsabilidades</option>
        <option value="Centro de Capacitación Puebla">Centro de Capacitación Puebla</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="sitio"><strong>Sitio:</strong></label></td>
      <td> 
    <!-- input donde se mostrara el sitio -->
    <input type='text' name="sitio" id='showSitio' readonly>
  </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo intentaré. Gracias.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, con esto guarde el nombre de la unidad sin alterar el input de abajo <3

Answer (score 0):

Ok mira creo que entiendo un poco tu problema, pero no entiendo por que querrías hacer eso en tu base de datos, te recomiendo normalizar, para evitar todo tipo de redundancias, lo que te recomiendo hacer es que crees una función de javascript en donde evalúes el valor que estas tomando del formulario esto lo puedes lograr con un switch y dependiendo de que valor estés tomando le asignas al valúe la cadena de texto que requeiras, aqui ya solo le asignas la cadena de caracteres que requeiras al valor del input, por lo que veo en tu formulario solo tomas el valor del option y lo asignas al input, pero eso es un tema de javascript.

Te quedaria un codigo como esto:

```
    function cambioUnidad()
    {
        var valor = document.getElementById('unidad').value;
    switch (valor) {
    case '1454':
       document.getElementById('showSitio').value='Opcion 1';
       break;
   case '40012':

  document.getElementById('showSitio').value='Opcion 2';
    break;
  case '2528':

  document.getElementById('showSitio').value='Opcion 3';
    break;
    default:
    document.getElementById('showSitio').value='Debes seleccionar una opcion valida';
    break;
            }
    }
```

Pero eso es Javascript, saludos

Comment: Lo probaré a ver que tal. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo lo siguiente mira porque justamente necesitaba varios valores.

```js
var opciones = {

  "0": ["", "", "", "", "Sin especificar"],
  "1": ["1", "1", "One Page", "3000", "900"]
}
function cambioOpciones()
{
  var combo = document.getElementById('opciones');
  var opcion = combo.value; 
  document.getElementById('contratado-secciones').value = opciones[opcion][0];
  document.getElementById('contratado-idioma').value = opciones[opcion][1];
  document.getElementById('contratado-tiempo').value = opciones[opcion][2];
  document.getElementById('contratado-costototal').value = opciones[opcion][3];
  document.getElementById('contratado-abonototal').value = opciones[opcion][4];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='opciones'  onchange='cambioOpciones();' class="form-control" style="background: #1176bc; color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1176bc;">
        <option value='0'>Selecciona un Plan</option>
        <option value='1'>One Page</option>
   </select>
   
   <br>
<input class="inputcentrado" type='text' id='contratado-secciones' value="Sin especificar" disabled/>
<br>
<input class="inputcentrado" type='text' id='contratado-idioma' value="Sin especificar" disabled/>
<br>
<input class="inputcentrado"  name="tipoweb" type='text' id='contratado-tiempo' placeholder="Sin Especificar"/>
<br>
<input type="text" id='contratado-costototal' value="Sin especificar"/>
<br>
<input type="text" id='contratado-abonototal' value="Sin especificar"/>
```

Creo que podria servirte porque da varios valores de 1 solo select.

Comment: Ya me da lo que quiero, de hecho el código hace lo que quiero, pero a la hora de guardar en la BD pues siempre toma el value del select, lo que yo quiero es que tome el texto, para que en la BD salga:

unidad: almacen

sitio: 1454

Y no como en la imagen que opuse :c

Comment: La solucion seria para mi "unidad = numero"  "nombre unidad = texto" y el texto lo tomaria de otro input. Bien lo podes hacer manual al input o hacer uno oculto usando el script que te mencione.